# Remove "error" mark from web.xml file (CDATA item)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, web.xml

I am getting user rolenames from LDAP, and some of them have spaces in between.

The whitespaces are now allowed as rolenames in `web.xml`, so Google told me to use `CDATA`.

```
<security-role>
  <role-name><![CDATA[GESMA Dispositivos Externos]]></role-name>
</security-role>
```

It works ok in the server, but Eclipse keeps marking the `web.xml` file as `error`. The error is `Value is not a valid NMToken`.

While only an annoyance, I find the mark very distracting. How can I get rid of it?

UPDATE: A minimal web.xml that shows the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <security-role>
    <role-name>GESMA</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name><![CDATA[GESMA Dispositivos Externos]]></role-name> <!-- Error HERE -->
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name><![CDATA[GESMA Hospital General]]></role-name> <!-- Error HERE -->
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name><![CDATA[GESMA Hospital Joan March]]></role-name> <!-- Error HERE -->
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name><![CDATA[GESMA Hospital Psiquiatric]]></role-name> <!-- Error HERE -->
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>GESMAN_Manager</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>GESMAN_Admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

My configuration is:

- Eclipse Indigo SR2 for Java EE
- JBossTools 3.3.0
- JBossAS Tools 2.3.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error/problem description Eclipse gives you?

Comment: @rolve you are right, added that info.

Comment: The error message indicates that it is expecting nmtoken(which cannot have spaces), and the cdata hack helps side-step one validation check, but is getting caught in another.

Comment: Would you mind posting the XML header (everything in the web-app tag)? Because the exact same thing validates fine in my Eclipse.

Comment: @rolve Added a minimal web.xml that still shows the same error, and my Eclipse configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. After digging through the various schema files of Java EE, I found that the type of `<role-name>` is indeed an xsd:token. This means that you cannot use spaces in there, even if you use a CDATA section.

The CDATA section just escapes characters that would normally not be allowed within an XML tag, such as `<` or `"`. But in the end, your space stays a space and is not allowed there. The server may not complain about this and everything may work, but according to the specification (the XML schemas), your file is not valid.

So I strongly suggest that you solve this problem by replacing the spaces with underscores or something and don't just shut Eclipse up. Because another server or even just a newer version may not accept your web.xml anymore.

(But of course there are ways to stop Eclipse from validating the file and if you want, I can post some of them here.)

---

**Edit:** Here are the relevant parts of the [Schema file](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_6.xsd) that is included from the [web.xml Schema file](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd). I think this is all the "documentation" you will find for this problem.

```
  <xsd:complexType name="role-nameType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>
        The role-nameType designates the name of a security role.
        The name must conform to the lexical rules for a token.
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="javaee:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

You see, it says the role names must conform to the rules of a token, meaning no spaces are allowed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference to the documentation? In this case, since I coded the login_module, I will be able to replace internally whitespace by underscores, but those role names come from the corporate LDAP and I will need some pushing to have them changed.